# Size of a Hello World android app

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I am new to android and when I create a simple Hello World app its size is about 900 KB. But I have seen many apps on play store like Chain Reaction having size of only 200 KB.
Do the default Hello World app contains some resources that I don't need? How to remove them?
Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There're some ways to reduce the size of the output APK file:

- Make sure there's no unused resources. You can check it using
  Android Lint Inspection. Just press **Control + Alt + Shift + i** and
  type "Unused resources" (without quotes). If there's unused
  resources, you can delete it manually.
- Use ProGuard see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).
- You can also combine ProGuard with Resource Shrinking. See [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking)